# How would you move database A to database B with tests?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, testing

I need some advice, I am working on a platform that is connected to a database with a certain structure that is no longer wanted by the company, So I need to find a way to move it to a new DB with different structure (the logic stays the same just the flow is different); for example, in Database A (old one) I have "user" table that contains types of users,
like "client", "buyer", "seller" etc...
all these entities are becoming new tables in Database B.
I am working with NodeJS and MySQL, I also need to test all the transfers and see if the numbers adds up.
What tools in NodeJS would you guys recommend me to use?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[see this it may help](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html)

> I have another idea but it's a little lengthy one, Extract all data into a CSV file from the older database and then feed it into a new Database.